# How to define reusable constants?

Tags: reason, reason-react

I have a Reason React component that looks like the following:

```rust
/* MyComponent.re */

let make = _children => {
    ...component,

    reducer: (action, state) => {
        switch (action) {
        | KeyDown(key) => switch (key) {
          | 13 => ReasonReact.Update(...)
          | _ => ReasonReact.NoUpdate
          }
        }
    },

    render: self => {
        <input _type="text" value=self.state.text
          onKeyDown=(event => self.send(KeyDown(ReactEventRe.Keyboard.keyCode(event)))) />
    }
};
```

Now I tried to refactor out the number `13` into a separate file:

```rust
/* Keys.re */

let enter = 13;
```

But I'm unable to use `Keys.enter` inside my `switch` statement in **MyComponent.re**. The error I get is:

```
Error: 275: <UNKNOWN SYNTAX ERROR>
```

I've also tried including the module directly inside **MyComponent.re** by adding:

```rust
module Keys = {
    let enter = 13;
};
```

at the top, but still get the same error.

My understanding of how modules work must be incorrect. What would be the correct way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's the issue with how the `module` is defined.

You could do the switch like this:

```
switch (key) {
| key when key === Keys.enter => ReasonReact.Update(...)
| _ => ReasonReact.NoUpdate
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks!
... but why does this work but not when I simply replace `13` with `Keys.enter` ?

Comment: Unlike `JavaScript`, `switch` in `reasonml` or `match` in `OCaml`/`F#` is a pattern matching. Although it can match `constant` like `13`, it can't be used to match value in variable without `when` guard.